# htpasswd a big list of user and pass

Tags: php, bash, .htpasswd

I got a script running on server , that generating a big file of user and password 
in format

```
   username ="johnuser"  password="johnpass"
   username ="adamuser"  password="adampass"
```

so on about 500 in list

This file is keep updating every 10 minute , with the list of users added or removed,
I want to use this username and password  to protect apache folder using htpasswd , is it possible to do that by any bash script that i can put in cron and can run 
to update my user list using htpasswd automatically .

Comment: Fast idea: You could hash the name/passwort with the needed hashfunction for `.htpasswd` and then save the output file as `.htpasswd`, meaning you create your `.htpasswd` file with your phpscript

Answer (score 0):

"I found this script for this type of purpose but not sure how to implement #!/bin/sh FILE=$1 FS=":" while read line do # store field 1 NAME=$(echo $line|cut -d$FS -f1) # store field 2 PASSWORD=$(echo $line|cut -d$FS -f2) /usr/local/apache/bin/htpasswd -b .htpasswd $NAME $PASSWORD done < $FILE"

"I will try to explain.

$FILE must have: user:pass line by line.
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
and etc.
Script is:`FILE=$1 FS=":"  while read line;  do NAME=$(echo $line|cut -d$FS -f1) PASSWORD=$(echo $line|cut -d$FS -f2)  htpasswd -b .htpasswd $NAME $PASSWORD; done < $FILE"`

Answer (score -2):

You should use PHP instead of Apache : [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: I found this script for this type of purpose but not sure how to implement                        #!/bin/sh

FILE=$1
FS=":" 
while read line
do
        # store field 1
        NAME=$(echo $line|cut -d$FS -f1)
        # store field 2
        PASSWORD=$(echo $line|cut -d$FS -f2)
/usr/local/apache/bin/htpasswd -b .htpasswd $NAME $PASSWORD
done < $FILE